# Como fazer essa busca de Query?

Tags: java, web-service, glassfish

Estou tentando desenvolver um webService Rest no Netbeans(Java).Para tal segui esse tutorial...

https://rafaelsakurai.gitbooks.io/desenvolvimento-distribuido/content/chapter10.1.html

Porem, na hora de rodar eu tenho um erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu depurei o projeto e encontrei o ponto de erro.Eu só não sei como resolver(todo meu conhecimento relacionado a webService vem do próprio tutorial).

O ponto de erro:

Classe DAO

```
public class PalestraDAO {
    private EntityManager em;

    public PalestraDAO(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

     public List<Palestra> consultarTodos() {
            Query q = em.createNamedQuery("TipoProduto.consultarTodos"); //<- Linha de erro
            return q.getResultList();
     }
}
```

Classe Entidade

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "TipoProduto.consultarTodos",
            query = "SELECT tpprod_nome FROM tipoproduto ORDER BY tpprod_nome")

        //String sql = "select tpprod_id, tpprod_idExt, tpprod_nome, tpprod_descricao, tpprod_imagem, tpprod_visibilidade, tpprod_configurado, tpprod_imagem64 from tipoproduto order by tpprod_nome;";

})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "tipoProduto_seq", sequenceName = "tipoProduto_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)

public class TipoProduto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2806694270931063283L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
      generator = "tipoProduto_seq")
    //private Long idEntidade;

    private int id;
    private int idExt;
    private String nome;
    private String descricao;
    private int imagem;
    private boolean visibilidade;
    private boolean configurado;
    private String imagem64;   

    public boolean isConfigura() {
        return configurado;
    }

    public void setConfigura(boolean configura) {
        this.configurado = configura;
    }



    public String getImagem64(){
        return imagem64;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setImagem64(String imagem64){
        this.imagem64 = imagem64;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public int getImagem() {
        return imagem;
    }

    public void setImagem(int imagem) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }


    public boolean isVisibilidade() {
        return visibilidade;
    }

    public void setVisibilidade(boolean visibilidade) {
        this.visibilidade = visibilidade;
    }

    public int getIdExt() {
        return idExt;
    }

    public void setIdExt(int idExt) {
        this.idExt = idExt;
    }






}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWL2x.png - O problema não seria o nome da Named Query errado?

Comment: @SULEIMANALVESDEMORAES não, o nome estava errado apenas aqui na questão, pois na hora de subir copiei parte do código do tutorial e parte do meu código...ai houve a divergência.

Comment: https://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-ajuda-ejb-exception/199718/5 de uma olhada

Answer (score 0):

Mas tá subindo a aplicação?
A `@NamedQuery` ainda tá errada.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "TipoProduto.consultarTodos",
        query = "SELECT tpprod_nome FROM tipoproduto ORDER BY tpprod_nome")
```

Deveria ser

```
@NamedQuery(name = "TipoProduto.consultarTodos",
        query = "SELECT tpprod.nome FROM tipoproduto tpprod ORDER BY tpprod.nome")
```